# Are Digital Signatures tuned to become harder as computers become faster?

Tags: digital-signature

For example, how long does a typical CPU take to verify a single secp256k1 signature? Wouldn't this need to change in time so that signatures can't be brute forced? How is it decided how "strong" the signature verification should be?

Comment: Given a digital signature and the public key corresponding to the private key used to create the signature, a typical CPU can verify a digital signature very quickly - in microseconds, or even nanoseconds.  However, without the private key, that same computer would require centuries (or even millenniums) to 'forge' the digital signature.  This is because digital signatures are based on 'trap-doors' - functions that are easy to verify, but hard to reverse.

Comment: Yes, I understand they are asymmetric. that wasn't my question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you need to check 2^128 = 10^38 keys to brute-force. Suppose your computer checks 10^9 keys/s. In a year this is ~3x10^16 keys. Let's round it up to 10^17. If you have 10^10 computers (more than the Earth population), you would check 10^27 passwords in a year.

CPUs are getting about 20% more powerful each year. If this trend remains for 100 years (which is hard to believe), the performance in 100 years would be 1.2^100 ~= 10^8 higher than now days. Means it would be possible to check 10^27 x 10^8 = 10^35 passwords in a year.

Means, even in 100 years later even when using the whole computer power on the Earth  will not be sufficient to brute-force a 128-bit password.

Thus, there is no need to consider other algorithms *because of increasing CPU power*.

But one should pay attention to cryptanalysis and what attacks are getting known each year.

How strong should the signature be? It depends on your threats, on your risks, on the benefits that an attacker can get by brute-forcing your signature.

Comment: and what about quantum computers ? In this link Google announced in October that its 53-qubit quantum processor had needed only 200 seconds to complete a problem that would have required 10,000 years on a supercomputer https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/quantum-computers-finally-beat-supercomputers-in-2019

Comment: @Nico: The OP is about CPUs. For quantum computers there is post-quantum crptography, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tags/post-quantum-cryptography/hot) for instance. Post your question at Crypto SE.

Comment: Even with quantum computing, brute-forcing a 256-bit keyspace requires a prohibitive amount of energy.  See the answer by ir01 at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year.